# Where is the setting that sets Experimental repo to lower priority?

Tags: apt

Suppose that I have enabled [Experimental](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianExperimental) in my "**/etc/apt/sources.list**". When I need to install anything from it, I have to explicitly specify on the command:

```
apt-get install wajig
# vs
apt-get --target-release experimental install wajig
```

Where is such a setting stored? I expected that it would be some sort of pinning, but I can't find anything suggesting such in "**/etc/apt/**". Also, is it possible to avoid the behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pinning of `experimental` and `backport` is in the repository itself (in the `Release` files). You can change the pinning as you wish, but you have to explicitly do it.

Look in [experimental Release file](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/experimental/Release) for the line `NotAutomatic: yes`. It comes from there.

You can see actual pinning values with `apt-cache policy wajig`.